# C#-Javascript to modify html page gotten from the web

Tags: c#

I am working in the branch of an international company. The mother company has imposed a 3rd party support tool to all the branches. This is a web based solution, hosted by the provider and accessed using https.

The issue is: - this tool is imposed and we don't have the choice not to use it - company standard is internet explorer - this tool can't meet local needs and the requirements of some european branches.

The issue in the european branche is as follow: - we don't want to store screenshots in the central solution because they may display information that we don't want to put outside of the country. - the names and the id of the european prospects/customers cannot be displayed.

As a consequence, it has been decided that no screenshot would be uploaded to the tool, and we will replace it by a fake link; and that no customer name or id would be put as well, but replaced by a fake id.

Now the consequence is when we will use the tool from these european countries, there are few screens that will not be usable anymore, because containing fake data: the screens with the screenshots and the screens with the customer names.

So we have to find a way to replace it on the fly, locally. The option is then: replace the fake image link by a real one; replace the fake id by a real one.

This process has to run locally.

We were thinking about using a man in the middle to apply the changes, but we have to forget this option as it would break the contract we have with the 3rd party provider.

So the only option I do see now, is an add-on, or a browser extension, which will, for the pages in scope, apply the changes described above.

As we also do use Internet explorer I was wondering what the best approach is. The code will have to call a service to retrieve the data from our local database. So a C# solution, being able to manage the credentials and call the services seems to be the solution.

But as I am not familiar with these technologies, I was wondering what the simplest technology would be. We can't invest too much just for few pages.

Am I obliged to write a C# add-on? Or can a js (e.g Kango) framework be used here?
What would you recommend?

Comment: Which version of IE do you have to support minimally? Maybe another idea might be to use the webbrowser control, and build a winforms app next to it specifically to browse those pages?

Comment: The current version is IE9